# KVM, configure video controler for virtual Windows 7

Tags: centos, kvm

I need to configure a virtual Windows 7 x64 for running games. I used the pre-installed KVM on CentOs 7 to install the virtual machine but unfortunately the video controller was not recognized as Nvidia GPU and no drivers could be installed.

The virtual Windows is running fine by itself. I searched the web for a way to configure the virtual video controller with no success. In one article, however, someone mentioned that KVM does not support 3D. Is that correct? If so, what other virtualization software can I use to make a fully functional Windows?

Comment: You need to set up passthrough of your Nvidia card. Here is a good blog on topic: http://vfio.blogspot.ru/2015/05/vfio-gpu-how-to-series-part-1-hardware.html (this is the link to the first part, read all posts of that guy since May '15) Remember, that you really need to install libvirt from virtpreview repository as this blog states.

Comment: Thank you.Please, write this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I am glad that this info have been useful, but I don't consider it to be a complete answer myself.